# Wiremock - 413 REQUEST ENTITY TOO LARGE when passing a very long token header

Tags: jetty, http-status-code-413, wiremock-standalone

I am using Wiremock standalone 2.26.3 and when I do a request to it, I always receive a http status code 413 Request Entity Too Large error.

The request uses an `Authorization: Bearer xxx` header and it's very long(7k chars). Other headers/cookies are several bytes only. I understand that it's the underlying Jetty which does not allow such long header.

Is there any way to bypass the limit?

Answer (score 0):

From wiremock doc, I found this: https://wiremock.org/docs/standalone/java-jar/

> **--jetty-header-buffer-size**: Deprecated, use --jetty-header-request-size. The Jetty buffer size for request headers, e.g. --jetty-header-buffer-size 16384, defaults to 8192K.
>
> **--jetty-header-request-size**: The Jetty buffer size for request headers, e.g. --jetty-header-request-size 16384, defaults to 8192K.

I think they are created just to bypass the limit and when I set it to `20000`, the error is gone and my stubs are served.

Comment: These configure the ENTIRE request / response header buffer size, not a specific header.  The error 4313 you are getting is unlikely to be caused by your `Authorization` header specifically, but likely something else in your request headers is growing out of hand (the most common culprit is `Cookie`, sometimes caused by bad client cookie expiration behaviors)

Comment: Oh thanks, so this is for all headers/cookies. I only have one long header which is `Authorization`(7k chars), others are trivial and much smaller, and changing this value indeed works for me, so I guess this is the solution. This is local test, and cookie is several bytes only.

Comment: And when I reduce the token size to several chars, without changing the buffer size it returns 200, so it must be the header.